# split() not producing expected results

Tags: python, split

I have a problem with python split which I can't figure out what I am missing that results in the split function not to work properly. I have been using similar splits before and they worked just fine.

```
content=open(file).read)()
Sep = content.split(r'Document [a-zA-Z0-9]{25}\n')
```

The file I am reading is something very easy as:

```
"I like coffee.

Document CLASSAR020181030eeat0000l

I like tea as well.

Document CLASSAR020181030eeat0000l

I like both coffee and tea."
```

Comment: What is your current output vs. the ideal output?

Comment: As an aside, you really should use a context manager to handle the file object and change the name of that variable.

Answer (score 3):

`str.split()` splits using a fixed delimiter, not a regular expression. You need to use `re.split()`.

```
import re
sep = re.split(r'Document [a-zA-Z0-9]{25}\n', content)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Error - regular expression syntax on string methods

`content` is a string. You cannot call the `split` method on this variable as it will invoke a `string`-based method that expects a separator. This separator must be a fixed string, and not a regular expression.

### Solution - Use re module

You can instead use methods within the regular expression module, as you're using regular expression syntax:

```
import re

with open(file, 'r') as fp:
    content = fp.read()

pattern = re.compile(r'Document \w{25}\n')
separated = pattern.split(content)
```

- The with block is just best practice for opening files in python. It
  is a context manager that automatically closes your file when you're
  finished. You may run into problems in the future if you don't use
  this.
- The regular expression I have used is slightly different to yours. It
  does exactly the same thing. However, `\w` is short for
  `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. I.e., it matches any alphanumeric character.
- We are using the split method again. However, this split method is part of the `re` module, not `string`, as our `pattern` variable is an `re` object.